# User specific reports in performance point

Tags: performancepoint

How can I show user or group specific reports in performance point.
I am using SSAS and SSRS for reports.

Currently same report is visible to every-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found it is that create reports for user-groups individually and assign necessary permissions.